# How copy value from jtextfield into jspinner

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jspinner

I have problem when I want to insert some hex value into JtextField and want to continue increment or decrement this value throw JSpinner. My problem is that my custom JSPinner always start increment value from 0 and I want to increment from exact position, which user will set in JTextfield

```
package opa.beta1;

import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.StringUtils;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.text.ParseException;
import javax.swing.AbstractSpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory;

public class TextFieldEvent {

    JTextField arrayIVnew[] = new JTextField[8];
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

    public void rewriteJSpinner(JSpinner jSpinner, JTextField array[], final int u) {
        Long tmp;
        tmp = new Long(array[u].getText());

        if (0 <= tmp && tmp <= 0xff && jSpinner.getValue() != tmp) {
            jSpinner.setValue(tmp);
        }
    }

    public String textXORing(JTextField array1[], JTextField array2[], int i) {

        String window1 = array1[i].getText();
        String window2 = array2[i].getText();
        if (window1.equals("")) {
            return array2[i].getText();
        }
        BigInteger pom1 = new BigInteger(window1, 16);
        if (window2.equals("")) {
            return array1[i].getText();
        }
        BigInteger pom2 = new BigInteger(window2, 16);
        BigInteger res = pom1.xor(pom2);
        String s = res.toString(16);
        return s;
    }

    public void createJSPinnerTextField(final JTextField array[], JPanel container, String s, int width,
            boolean docListener, boolean edit) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            array[i] = new JTextField(width);
            array[i].setText(s);
            final int u = i;

            final JSpinner jSpinner = new JSpinner(new TextFieldEvent.LongNumberModel(0x00L, 0x00L, 0xFFL, 1L));

            //jspinnerarray[i]= jSpinner;
            JSpinner.DefaultEditor editor = (JSpinner.DefaultEditor) jSpinner.getEditor();
            JFormattedTextField tf = editor.getTextField();
            tf.setFormatterFactory(new TextFieldEvent.MyFormatterFactory());

            Dimension d = jSpinner.getPreferredSize();
            d.setSize(16, 20);
            jSpinner.setPreferredSize(d);

            jSpinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
                    int tmp = 0;
                    tmp = Integer.parseInt(jSpinner.getValue().toString());
                    array[u].setText(String.valueOf(Integer.toHexString(tmp)).toUpperCase());
                    tmp++;
                }
            });

            container.add(jSpinner);

            if (edit) {
                array[i].setEditable(false);
            }
            if (docListener) {
                array[i].getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {

                        rewriteJSpinner(jSpinner, array, u);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {

                        rewriteJSpinner(jSpinner, array, u);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                        rewriteJSpinner(jSpinner, array, u);
                    }
                });
            }
            container.add(array[i]);
        }
    }

    private static class LongNumberModel extends AbstractSpinnerModel {

        private Long value, stepSize;
        private Comparable<Long> minimum, maximum;

        public LongNumberModel(Long value, Long minimum, Long maximum, Long stepSize) {
            this.value = value;
            this.minimum = minimum;
            this.maximum = maximum;
            this.stepSize = stepSize;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(Object value) {
            this.value = (Long) value;
            fireStateChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getNextValue() {
            long v = value.longValue() + stepSize.longValue();
            return bounded(v);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getPreviousValue() {
            long v = value.longValue() - stepSize.longValue();
            return bounded(v);
        }

        private Object bounded(long v) {
            if ((maximum != null) && (maximum.compareTo(v) < 0)) {
                return null;
            }
            if ((minimum != null) && (minimum.compareTo(v) > 0)) {
                return null;
            }
            return Long.valueOf(v);
        }
    }

    private static class MyFormatterFactory extends DefaultFormatterFactory {

        @Override
        public JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter getDefaultFormatter() {
            return new TextFieldEvent.HexFormatter();
        }
    }

    private static class HexFormatter extends DefaultFormatter {

        @Override
        public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
            try {
                return Long.valueOf(text, 16);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                throw new ParseException(text, 0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
            return Long.toHexString(
                    ((Long) value).intValue()).toUpperCase();
        }
    }

    public void addComponentsToPanel(Container panel) {

        panel.setLayout(null);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Inicialization vector:");
        panel1.add(label1);
        createJSPinnerTextField(arrayIVnew, panel1, "11", 2, false, false);
        panel.add(panel1);
        Insets insets = panel.getInsets();
        Dimension size = panel1.getPreferredSize();
        panel1.setBounds(10 + insets.left, 485 + insets.top, size.width, size.height);
    }

    TextFieldEvent() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Oracle Padding Attack");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addComponentsToPanel(frame.getContentPane());
        Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
        frame.setSize(800 + insets.left + insets.right, 650 + insets.top + insets.bottom);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TextFieldEvent();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: You've likely got recursion going on somewhere. If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Which line is 101 from the Attack.java class? Which is line 159?

Comment: 101 line is:jSpinner.setValue(new Long(Integer.parseInt(array[u].getText().toString())).longValue()); 159 line is :fireStateChanged();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the value of a JSpinner from within a ChangeListener -- which will call the ChangeListener, which will then change the value of the JSpinner -- which will call the ChangeListener, which will then change the value of the JSpinner -- which will call the ChangeListener, which will then change the value of the JSpinner -- which will call the ChangeListener, which will then change the value of the JSpinner -- which will call the ChangeListener, which will then change the value of the JSpinner -- which will call the ChangeListener, which will then change the value of the JSpinner -- which will call the ChangeListener, which will then change the value of the JSpinner -- .... ad infinitum.

Don't do this.

Comment: I've moved changing value of JSpinner into jtextfield listener, but now i have Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KCY2ArDW
Here is example how I changed it

Comment: Please post a [minimal code example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here as an edit to your question as has been requested of you before. Please at least read the link.

Comment: I have posted minimalized code

Comment: @DahakkaSVK: OK, 1) what problems does the minimal code show us? and 2) it seems to be missing a class, `JTextFieldCharLimit`? Is this class necessary for demonstration of your problem? If not, then you will want to get all references to it out of your code. If so, then we'll need that class.

Comment: I have fixed it. Code shows us that when I want to increment JTextfield from e.g value 11 it will start from 0 nor 11